# How to solve TemplateDoesNotExist in Django?

Tags: python, django

[image]

settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
    url(r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    url(r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
]
```

views:

```
def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    t = get_template('current_datetime.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'current_date': now}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

current_datetime.html:

```
<html><body>It is now {{ current_date }}.</body></html>
```

And I got this:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /time/
current_datetime.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/time/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
current_datetime.html
Exception Location: /Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 25
Python Executable:  /Users/wonderful/anaconda/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    

    ['/Users/wonderful/mysite',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python27.zip',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.6-py2.7.egg',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa',
     '/Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg']

Server time:    Tue, 7 Feb 2017 10:42:42 +0800

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/wonderful/mysite/mysite/templates/current_datetime.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/current_datetime.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/wonderful/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/current_datetime.html (Source does not exist)
```

How to solve it?

Comment: looks like it is expecting the templates directory to be in the inner `mysite` directory

Comment: @karthikr yes,it works

Comment: Your folder is named "template" and in your settings you have described it "templates"

Comment: @Bijoy I have corrected it after the taking this screenshot,but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't provide the accurate template absolute path.

go to your template folder and run `pwd` in terminal, you will get the absolute path, and then replace it with your current `DIRS` and see whether it works or not.

You can print out your os.path.dirname(__file__) and see whether it's identical with the abs path you got by `pwd`

The `templates` directory is in the same path level as `mysite`, in my understanding it should be:
`os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`